# SOAP Response retorando NULL

Tags: java, soap

Estou realizando a comunicação com um webservice SOAP, por meio da IDE eu consigo executar as chamadas dos métodos e capturar os valores perfeitamente, porém, ao executar o .jar gerado pelo IntelliJ, todos os retornos são null...
Já tentei gerar o .jar pelo maven, estou sem idéia do que possa ser...

Exemplo de um dos métodos que estou utilizando:

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "InserirVenda", action = "Linker20/InserirVenda")
@WebResult(name = "InserirVendaResponse", targetNamespace = "Linker20", partName = "parameters")
public InserirVendaResponse inserirVenda(
        @WebParam(name = "InserirVenda", targetNamespace = "Linker20", partName = "parameters")
                InserirVenda parameters);
```

Comment: O que seu Client retorna? Ele retorna algum código de erro ? você já testou a chamada por uma ferramenta como por exemplo o SOAP UI, etc..

Comment: Eles retornam um objeto contendo a mensagem de sucesso/erro. Pelo SOAP UI eu consigo capturar o retorno... Mas acho que agora encontrei o problema. O Webservice deles foi compilado em uma versão antiga do java, enquanto minha versão é superior, realizei um teste com uma versão mais velha e funcionou... Obrigado

Comment: Pode ser ! você gerou o cliente a partir do WSDL como ?

Comment: Gerei ele pelo comando wsimport e também tentei pela IDEA, ambos estavam com o mesmo problema, quando eu gerava o .exe não conseguia  capturar nenhum retorno... Vou pedir para os responsáveis pela plataforma compilarem o WSDL utilizando a versão mais atual do JAVA !

Comment: Acho melhor fazer asim!!